# how to change Firestore document data using Google Cloud Functions in node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am trying to write a google cloud function that will check all documents under a collection in every minute and if a boolean parameter after 15 minutes later still false, it will change another document parameter.

[image: this is the collection that cloud function will check every 1 minute. there is only one document inside it. But it could be more]

[image: this is the document that cloud function will change the data using the other document info]

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.scheduledFunctionAppointment =
functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun((context) => {

    
        const timestamp = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
     
    
    return getReceivers(mUserGroup).then((snapshot) => {
        
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            
            const mAppointmentObj = doc.data();
            
            const mAppointmentCreationDate = mAppointmentObj.appointmentCreationDate;
            const mAppointmentDate = mAppointmentObj.appointmentDate;
            const mChaplainId = mAppointmentObj.chaplainId;
            const mAppointmentId = mAppointmentObj.appointmentId;
            const mIsAppointmentPaymentDone = mAppointmentObj.isAppointmentPaymentDone;


            if (timestamp-mAppointmentCreationDate >= 900000){
            
                if(mIsAppointmentPaymentDone === false){
                    admin.firestore().collection('chaplains').doc(mChaplainId).collection('chaplainTimes').doc('availableTimes').update({
         
            mAppointmentId: {
                isBooked: false
            }
    
                    });

                }

            }
            
        });

    });

})

async function getTaskAppointments() {
    const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('appointment_temporary').get();
    return snapshot;
}
```

the code should check the appointment_temporary collection in every 1 minute. In every check, it will take the server time and appointment creation date. If after 15 minutes later, isAppointmentPaymentDone still false, it will make isBooked false that under availableTimes map data.

I wrote a function but it gives error. I am a mobile developer. I am not familiar with the node.js. Thank you very much for the help in advance.

Comment: "it gives error" Always include the complete, exact error message and stack trace in the question please.

Comment: Also: If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.